# How to resolve dockerfile, and docker-compose when main go files are in nested directory?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am very new to Docker so please forgive me, but I have a working dockerfile and docker-compose when the Main.go is at root-level but in this project the app will break if I put main.go at root.

File Structure

```
queue-backend
- .idea
- cmd
  - appCode
    - handler.go
    - helper.go
    - main.go
    - routes.go
- pkg
  - forms
  - models
    - mongodb
    - models.go
- tmp
.gitignore
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
go.mod
README.md
db
extensions
```

Anyway... my dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM golang:1.16

WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

COPY ../.. .
RUN curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmtrek/air/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin

CMD ["air"]
```

Docker-compose.yml looks like

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  backend:
    build: ""
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - mongodb_container
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: queue-delivery
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

I have tried to set WORKDIR to `/app/cmd/appCode` or `/cmd/appCode` and matching the same in the docker-compose to `.:/app/cmd/appCode` and `.:/cmd/appCode` which none work, it always returns this, or the stated paths above instead of just the '/app' path

```
backend_1            | no Go files in /app
backend_1            | failed to build, error: exit status 1
```

At this point, I'm not sure what else to try...

Comment: Do you need a live reloading tool here?  Can you `COPY . .`, `RUN go install ./cmd/appCode`, and remove the `volumes:` mount?  It looks like you could [configure `air` to rebuild the Docker image too](https://github.com/cosmtrek/air/blob/master/air_example.toml#L10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve Dockerfile in docker-compose.yml you need to change the build section as below

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    backend:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            - mongodb_container

    mongodb_container:
        image: mongo:latest
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: queue-delivery
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
            - mongodb_data_container:/data/db

volumes:
    mongodb_data_container:
```

Your Dockerfile has some issues,

```
FROM golang:1.16

WORKDIR /app
# File changes must be added at the very end, to avoid the installation of dependencies again and again
RUN curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmtrek/air/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .  # can not find this file in the directory structure
RUN go mod download

COPY ../.. .  # doesn't make sense, just use COPY . .

CMD ["air"]
```

Comment: So I receive ```backend_1            | can't load package: package .: no Go files in /app
backend_1            | failed to build, error: exit status 1
``` when I run "docker-compose up --build" do I need to change. the WORKDIR?

Comment: Fixed working directory, disregard, thank you for your answer! :~)